# 2 images with @2x size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 5

Tags: ios, iphone

For iPhone 6, 5s, 5 we use `@2x` images. But width of iPhone 6 is more then iPhone 5. I have a image view in my ViewController.

The images are named as:

```
image.png - 320*100
image@2x.png - 640*200
image@3x.png - 1242*300
```

It works fine for iPhone 5, 5s, and 6+. But device width for iPhone 6 is 375. So it needs `750*200`.

How to add an image of this size? What should it's name be?

Comment: Why is your image wider on iPhone6? Autolayout? If so, you need to detect it, and give it a different name (like "image_375"). The normal @2x resolution won't automatically detect different aspect ratios.

Comment: The problem can't be solved by changing the name of image. You'd better use vector graph or change the UI design.

Comment: On iphone 6 its wider becaouse, I need image to go from left to right. Take full width of device. Left and right contraint constant is '0'.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7 or newer, you can use **image xcaassets**. It helps you to set your images for iphone 5 5s 6 and 6+

Comment: That's not an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6 is using the "@2x" image. When you set the image name, you only need to set the name without any prefix. The system will automatically load the right image for you if you have given it the right version.

Just for more info, here is the link:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1

Comment: I know that. I am using only image name. But it takes 640*200 size. So it do not fit in iphone 6. Because iphone 6 is 350 point and 750 pixels in width.

Comment: The docs said that iPhone5 and 6 are in the same category. Check it out.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your problem? What do you mean it does not work? It's not showing? It's not crapping properly? Or it's blur?